# How to store regex match in a variable to use with Search/Replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to capture a word using a pattern and store somewhere to use in replace operation:

For instance I have this text

```
ab iiids
as sasas
md aisjaij
as asijasija
```

I am able to capture everething before the first space using the following pattern:

```
.*?(?=[" "])
```

Let´s say I could use '$' to represent the match in the search and replace so I would like to have the following in the replace field

```
INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES ("$")
```

Could not find a solution.
Is this even possible?

Comment: You could use capturing groups. For example the following pattern `(a)bc`, this will match `abc`. The replacement would look like `$1foo`. So if there was `abc` as input, the output would be `afoo`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `$&` or `$0` represents the entire match in the replacement string:

```
Find what: .*?(?=[ ])
Replace with: INSERT INTO table \(value\) VALUES \("$0"\)
```

Note that you don't need the quotes inside the character class. Otherwise your match will stop at a quote as well. Also note, that there is another catch, that you have to escape parentheses in the replacement string (thanks to acdcjunior for noticing that). That's because Notepad++ uses boost, which supports a parenthesis-delimited conditional construct.

Using your input, this will result in

```
INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES ("ab") iiids
INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES ("as") sasas
INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES ("md") aisjaij
INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES ("as") asijasija
```

For more advanced use cases, you can wrap parts of the regex in parentheses, and reference the substrings they matched with `$1`, `$2`, and so on.

By the way, a more explicit pattern would be:

```
^[^ ]*(?=[ ])
```

This makes sure that you don't get additional matches where you don't want them.

Finally, [here is a reference](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Regular_Expressions#Substitutions) of all the things you can do in the replacement string.